# Are there guard clauses in Twig?

Tags: twig

Do you know of a way to write a guard clause in Twig?

I am writing a template and instead of wrapping `foo` in a if statement like this:

```
{% if foo is not empty %}
    // code for foo 
{% endif %}
```

Id like to do this:

```
{% if foo is empty %}
    {% return %}
{% endif %}
// code for foo
```

I checked the documentation and could not find anything.

https://twig.symfony.com/

Comment: Nope, there is no such thing in twig, you can't even for example break out of a for loop